# What are some adjectives that mean 'subordinate alternative'?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Sentence for Context: Please contact Ann preferably via email, or ___ by telephone.

'alternatively' and 'secondarily' are ambiguous, because it can just mean that telephone is a coequal, without revealing Ann's aversion to it.

'subordinately'  does impart Ann's dislike, but is this a right word?

Comment: Since you already said _preferably_ about email, the implication is that anything else is less preferable.

Comment: @Barmar has it right. You could say _else_ after _or_, but it's not necessary.

Comment: You could say, "Please contact Ann preferably via email, or, **if necessary**, by telephone."

Answer (score 1):

Because you already stated the preferred method, you could just say

> , or if necessary by telephone.

Comment: Or, to really convey a tone of disgust, try "or if you must, by telephone".